# Inno Setup: Unable to delete folder during uninstallation

Tags: inno-setup

we are using delete, removedir, deltree functions to delete the files and folders during the uninstallation of our product.
so some times these functions are unable to delete the files (mostly .lck files and sparse files), at that time the above functions are giving us just true/false boolean values, but we need the exact error behind the failure. So, is there any function to capture exact error messages?

Comment: Why don't you just use the [`[UninstallDelete]`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_uninstalldeletesection.htm) section ?

Comment: Can [UninstallDelete] section be used to get the error messages?

Comment: No, but if a deletion of an installed item fails, the uninstaller reports that to the user. I've checked (yet) the `RemoveDir` function in the source code and it should set the last error code, so you should be able to get it by using e.g. `MsgBox(SysErrorMessage(DLLGetLastError), mbError, MB_OK)`, though the last error is reset to 0 even if the `RemoveDir` function fails, so it's either a bug or there's something else been called immediately after. I'll try to look closer, but I'm busy right now, so maybe later on.

Comment: TLama@ any updates on above problem.

Comment: I couldn't find a way how to get the last error info. So by my opinion it's impossible to get this information.

Comment: Pity. It's probably worth an enhancement request, particularly for _DelTree_ and _DeleteFile_. It means they have to change the return value of the functions though.